How to properly size R and C in a low-pass filter with known load impedance?
In Horowitz and Hill's The Art of Electronics, an exercise after Ch. 1 prompts the reader to design a simple RC high-pass filter.  It should have a -3db point of 10Hz.  Further, the designed should assume that the filter is driven by a source with zero impedance; it will drive a load with 10k impedance.
The answer provided here suggests that you plan to have the resistor fixed at 1/100 of the load impedance, or 100 ohms.  Using the formula for high pass filters $$f = 1/{2\pi RC}$$ it is easy to arrive at their suggested answer.  The resistor should be $$R = 100\Omega$$ ohms and the capacitor approx. $$C = 160\mu F$$
This thinking makes sense to me.  The resistor will be in parallel with the load and so will not really be affected by 10k resistance.  What I don't get is the next question.
Assuming the same source and load impedances, we are to design a low-pass filter with is 3dB point at 10kHz.  To do this, I applied the same thinking.

I was aiming for the reactance of the capacitor (which will be in parallel to the load) to be that same 100 ohms.  I got
$$ X_c= 1/{2\pi fC}$$
$$ 100\Omega = 1/{2\pi *10kHz* 1.57 \mu F}   $$
So at 1.57 uF I should see a reactance of 100 ohms.  With this capacitor in mind, a resistor of approx 10 ohms would give...
$$f=1/{2\pi RC}$$
$$10kHz = 1/{2\pi 10\Omega * 1.57 \mu F}$$

It seems to me that I have gotten the 3dB point where I want it, and the capacitor is set in the same way as the resistor was in the previous problem.  Their solution, however, is
$$R = 1.6kHz$$ $$ C=.01\mu F$$
I don't understand what makes their solution better.  I'm sure it is better, but why?


The 100 Ohm in the HP is quite a heavy load for the source. Why not get rid of it entirely  and just put ~1.6uF in front of the 10k load? A 1.6 kOhm + 10 nF LP filter  doesn't give you a 10 kHz BW as the 10 kOhm load is effectively in parallel with the 1.6 kOhm resistor which puts the 3 dB cutoff somewhere around 11.5 kHz.

You really should specify the edition (there are 3 of them) and the exercise numbers. Page numbers would also help.
To put this into context, you are discussing the following exercises found on page 66 of the 3rd edition:
\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\$
I don't know where you got the right answers for either, above. I just have to accept them.
You have a circuit like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
If you refer to Figure 1.100(A) on page 49, you will see this:

I've circled their selection (as you quote it.)
That chart does not take into account the loading by the \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ load. But it does show that the values (assuming an unloaded RC filter) look very, very close to what you quoted.
One thing to keep in mind is that for simple RC circuits, there is an inflection point in the phase angle curve right at \$45^\circ\$. And this also corresponds to where the output is \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ below its maximum.
These two ideas are often conflated. One might say \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ when what is really meant is the phase angle inflection point. Your low-pass case is an example of where the phase angle inflection point does not occur where the output is \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ relative to the input source. However, it is still true that the output, at the phase angle inflection point, will be \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ relative to where it would be near DC. It's important to get your head wrapped around what I just wrote in this paragraph.
In the answer you say is right, the critical angular frequency (the point where the phase shift is \$45^\circ\$) will be \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{\left(R_1\,\mid\mid\, R_{_\text{L}}\right)\,C_1}=72500\:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$ (about \$f_{_0}\approx 11.539\:\text{kHz}\$) and the near-DC gain will be \$A=\frac1{1+\frac{R_1}{R_{_\text{L}}}}\approx 0.8621\$ (about \$-1.29\:\text{dB}\$.) However, at \$\omega_{_0}\$ the output will be down another \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$, for a total of about \$-4.30\:\text{dB}\$. So this is a case where the \$-3.01\:\text{dB}\$ point for the output occurs before reaching the critical angular frequency. The reason is that you have a resistor divider that also attenuates the input signal, even near DC.
Just for validation:

So their question isn't entirely clear on that point. But at least you can see from Figure 1.100(A) where they might have gotten their values. The effective source impedance is enough lower (less impacted by) than the load impedance to be acceptable, perhaps. (It could be made still lower, of course.)
Can you provide the source for the answers they gave you?
